# There are 2 google analytics event fired in one page, i want only one analytic to fire in that page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have two Google analytic s event in one page. I only want one Google analytic event. Is there anyway i can remove one so when i open that page, only one Google analytic can be seen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

and,

```
<script type=text/java-script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    _gaq.push(['_addTrans','7000004','380194','99.99','7.27','20','Richfield','MN','US']);
    _gaq.push(['_addItem','7000004','38361','Power Shovel (38361)','','99.99','1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 'Google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

I want second one to delete.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, this should be really easy to resolve.

It looks like you've got two identical blocks calling Google Analytics (on the account UA-31277529-1), the first is just the vanilla add-to-the-page code supplied by Google.

The second block includes the same initialization but also pushes a couple of additional pieces of information to Analytics (eCommerce tracking?).  Essentially, you've got redundancy in the set-up and page tracking because of that first block.

So, I'm assuming that you want to both:

- track page visitors via Analytics;
- *and* track the additional eCommerce attributes you're pushing.

Then, all you need to do is remove the first code block and use only the second one:

```
<script type=text/java-script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31277529-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    _gaq.push(['_addTrans','7000004','380194','99.99','7.27','20','Richfield','MN','US']);
    _gaq.push(['_addItem','7000004','38361','Power Shovel (38361)','','99.99','1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 'Google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

This will still track your page views, but will also track your eCommerce objects, which should all occur in one, single 'fire'.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My problem is i have the second one in my code. When i buy something and then in Order Confirmation Page, it shows those analytic s which is fine. The problem is when i go to Order History Page,i see both Google Analytic. i don't want to see the second one . I only want to see the first Google Analytic. I am not sure if my question is clear. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Hi @tshetensherpa, glad to be of help!  If your question is answered, please don't forget to put a green tick against the correct answer to help future visitors to Stack overflow find the relevant answers.

It sounds like your additional problem relates to the templates you're using to display your order history page.  Your best bet would be to find and edit that template to remove that second block.  If it's being inherited from the master template, you will need to wrap that second block in logic to not use it in order history pages.

Comment: That being the case, your best bet would be to open up a new question, and make sure that you define which template/system you're using (you don't mention which system you're using in your present question), and explain the situation.  I suspect this is something that will need PHP logic, but it's not possible to help you further without a lot more information on the environment you're using.